# Android: How can I exchange data between multiple still running activities directly?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I need a nice way to exchange data between two activities directly. I have one same custom title for all my  running activities and in my first activity I display the GPS state in that title with an image (found/still searching). The `LocationListener` is in my first activity and if the GPS state changes, I would like to update all the titles of my running/displayed activities. At the moment I can only change the title of my first activity.

I know that I can exchange the data through the SharedPreferences and by Intents which passes the data as Extras but as far as I know, I can only receive the extras in the onCreate Methods of my other activities.

What I want do have is, that the data is updated on a still running activity (onCreate is passed).

I hope you understand what I mean :)

Example scenario:

I start up my App. The GPS localisation is running (first Activity). Meanwhile I navigate to another activity of my App. Now, If the GPS state changes I need to update the title of my second activity which is shown at the moment.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Use a single `Activity` and two `Fragments` instead of two `Activities`.

Comment: Well, you can use SingletonPattern or ObserverPattern

Comment: Like Squonk was saying, you could use a single activity and have many fragments.  The activity would handle data between each fragment.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for the quick help. I try to solve it with fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from creating an activity with two fragments, there is a tricky way that serves for other scenarios :

Let's say, if you have an variable (let the text in the title bar is an variable) that needs to keep update, while it's impossible to use broadcast (message missing is not allowed or activity is killed), you can use the text saving from shared preference, and extract it every single time.

For example, Activity A uses String from sharepreference, key is "title", and default value is your app name. After B, C or D updates the title text, A also needs to update. So you just update the value of key "title" in share preference. After A is revoked, it will grasp the title in sharedPreference again and update the title accordingly.

Hope this help. :-)